# A* search heuristic for TSP with benefit and cost?

Tags: algorithm, search, traveling-salesman

I would like to solve a `TSP` problem with benefit and cost. 
Let us say A salesman has a set of customers to visit each visit will take cost of moving time from the current location to the location of a customer and as well as visit duration. Meanwhile the benefit is a numeric score that a Salesman will get from visiting a customer. The salesman has a time limitation, hence he should visit a set of customers (not necessary all) that gives him maximum net `benefit = score - travel time`. The Salesman must return to his initial location in the given time.

`A*` expands the node with least cost function `f(n) = g(n) + h(n)` and return the path to the goal which has the lowest cost.

If I can determine the `g(n)` as the net benefit aforementioned. What is the best way to determine `h(n)` ?

I know this is a combinatorial problem similar to orienteering problem. 
Is it possible to solve this problem using `A*` ?
Actually the path does not need to be optimal. I just want to have a path that gives the maximum net benefit (reverse to the cost in `A*`)

Comment: [Where should I post questions about algorithms?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519/where-should-i-post-questions-about-algorithms-stack-overflow-or-programmers-se): [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @RubensFarias when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)